# Number of components of algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For (real or complex) algebraic varieties given by some explicit polynomials, are there methods to compute the number of connected components?

Comment: In which topology?

Comment: As a closed subset of <math>\R^n</math> or <math>\C^n</math> for their standard (euclidean) topology.