# Method for defining a number of connected components of real algebraic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

The question is simple: given the concrete polynomial $f(x,y,z)$ ($x$,$\,$ $y$ and $z$ are real numbers), is there any method for answering this question for a surface $f(x,y,z) = 0$? I'm interested in number of connected components with respect to Euclidean topology. My Google search was unsuccesful and MSE search found that someone had [almost the same question as mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647388/number-of-components-of-algebraic-variety) a year before, but this question hadn't been answered. I would be very glad to be pointed to a reference (MSE link or anything else) that answers this question. Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Downvotes without explanations? I surely love them.

Comment: Не беспокойтесь, Евгений, ето отличный вопрос: +1.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, thanks (или спасибо :) ). I thought that it won't be hard to find a reference, but I hadn't succeeded and so here I am.

Comment: Do you know about [Harnack's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_curve_theorem) for curves? I know you're asking about surfaces but maybe this gives you some entry point to the literature — it seems like a natural question to ask next.

Comment: @Hoot Well, my faculty curricula told me nothing about algebraic geometry (we just don't have it), but I've met such things as Harnack's theorem before, still I have no experience dealing with them. Still thank you for a recommendation!